# Can Solr boost results on number of social "likes"?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, scoring

I am trying to order the results based on the **number of "likes"**.

The most obvious solution is to have a "likes" field for each row and re-index the document for every user who clicks "like". But re-indexing large documents isnt practical in this case.

---

(following is for the sake of example: no large documents involved)

Ideally, I would like to index both the data and the user actions in Solr as separate rows.

The **data rows** (as shown below) are relatively stable over time.

```
id:place_1 
title: ela restaurant
meta: sea food, chinese food festival
description: this place...
```

The **action rows** are inserted each time the user clicks "like".

```
id:action_43141
action:like
user:john
target:place_1

id:action_44323
action:like
user:doe
target:place_1
```

---

How can I boost a result based on the **number of likes**, given that each like exist on it's own row?

---

I know there exist joins in the upcoming Solr 4.0 http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join . But would it improve scores based on **number** of matching rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ExternalFileField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html). There isn't a lot of documentation about it at the moment, but see [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/potter-timothy-boosting-documents-in-solr/10).

Comment: Right on target :-) But help on ExternalFileField is too hard to come by. I guess your answer here is relavent http://stackoverflow.com/a/6333828/604511

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at click-through 
relevance ranking [presentation](http://www.lucidimagination.com/sites/default/files/Bialecki_Andrzej_Click_through_relevance_ranking_in_Solr_LucidWorks_Enterprise.pdf)

Comment: There are quite a number of commercial implementations that support social scoring.