# Solr: Sorting by term specific click-through rates

Tags: mongodb, solr

We presently have Solr deployed across multiple servers on our image sharing site. We have 10 million images, with 1/4 million added monthly.

So far Solr does a very good job at selecting search results, but we think there is room to improve on sorting/ranking. We think that incorporating click-through rates in the rankings would provide significantly improved results.

We presently collect click-through data via MongoDB. We record how many times an image is clicked on vs. how many times it is displayed, per term. So for example:

> [image identifier], [search term], [click-through rate]
>
> "00000001", "banana peel", "0.1565"
>
> "00000001", "banana", "0.0216"
>
> "00000001", "monkey banana", "0.0087"

What we want to do is find a way to incorporate this search-term-specific click-through data into our Solr rankings. The more an image has been clicked on for that same term, the higher it will rank. We have yet been able to find a way to do this cleanly.

We would like to load the data externally, and not have it as part of the Solr index - as we'd like the click-through data to be nearly real-time and would like to keep our Solr catalogue from getting too huge.

Any ideas or thoughts would be **very** much appreciated!

Comment: I asked a question like this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411860/can-solr-boost-results-on-number-of-social-likes . AFAIK I would choose from ExternalFileField, reindexing that document, or join (solr 4.0 onward) a occasionally-updated "meta" document with a frequently-updated "scoring" document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExternalFileField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html) is the most obvious solution.

Also check http://www.slideshare.net/LucidImagination/bialecki-andrzej-clickthroughrelevancerankinginsolrlucidworksenterprise-8419715 for some more background on this issue.