# Can reindex time be reduce when boosting is changed in Sunspot

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am trying to fine-tune the column boost in Sunspot. However it is said that every time I change the search index block in model I need to reindex for it to take effect. However reindexing takes 20 minutes.

Since boosting/weight of a column should be store separately from fulltext information itself, is it possible to reduce this reindex time (or do I need to reindex that at all?)

Comment: I asked a similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411860/can-solr-boost-results-on-number-of-social-likes

Comment: My answer below makes an assumption about your code, please provide a better example if my assumption is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably be best served to insert your boosting information in the `qf` parameter at search time.

For Sunspot, if you're talking about the boost in this context:

```
searchable do
  text :title, :boost => 2
end
```

Then the advice to reindex doesn't quite apply. That particular boost option is indeed applied at query time via the Solr `qf` parameter.

Comment: yes this is the way I specify a column to be boosted (in model). Thanks for saving me so much time.

Comment: sorry but it seems to have no effect if I boost an irrelevant field to 10. After changing the model I restarted the rails server, but the ordering seems unchanged.